# How to test XQuery function with map argument

Tags: testing, dictionary, xquery, exist-db

I'd like to test an eXist-db XQuery function that takes [Map datatype](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/wiki/blogs/eXist/XQueryMap) argument. According to the [eXist-db test framework guide](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/xqsuite.xml):

> XQuery annotation parameters need to be literal values, so only
>   strings and numbers are allowed. XQSuite thus applies type conversion
>   to every argument as well as to values used in assertions.

However, I could not find how to specify a Map datatype as a string. Here is an example code that I have:

```
declare 
    %test:arg("input", "{p1}?id={id}") 
    %test:arg("props", "id") 
    %test:arg("props", "ABC") 
    %test:assertEquals("{p1}?id=ABC")
function properties:substitute($input as xs:string, $props as map (xs:string, xs:string)) as xs:string {
    let $keys := map:keys($props)
    let $tokens := $keys ! concat('\{', ., '\}')
    let $replacements := $keys ! $props(.)
    return functx:replace-multi($input, $tokens, $replacements)
};
```

The test fails with the following error:

```
<testcase name="substitute"  class="properties:substitute">
<error type="java:org.exist.xquery.XPathException"  message="exerr:ERROR XPTY0004: The actual cardinality for parameter 2 does not match the cardinality declared in the function's signature: properties:substitute($input as xs:string, $props as map) xs:string. Expected cardinality: exactly one, got 3. [at line 7, column 5]
In function:
    properties:substitute(xs:string, map) [7:5:/db/apps/ssg/modules/properties.xql]
    test:apply(function, item()*) [327:9:jar:file:/C:/Programs/eXist-db/exist.jar!/org/exist/xquery/lib/xqsuite/xqsuite.xql]
    test:apply(function, element(), item()*) [234:9:jar:file:/C:/Programs/eXist-db/exist.jar!/org/exist/xquery/lib/xqsuite/xqsuite.xql]
    test:call-test(function, element(), element()*) [135:32:jar:file:/C:/Programs/eXist-db/exist.jar!/org/exist/xquery/lib/xqsuite/xqsuite.xql]"/>
</testcase>
```

Any ideas how to make it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the following reply in the mailing list:

> Sorry, that’s not possible. A map does not have a simple string
>   representation. You will have to write a helper function for the test,
>   which generates the map, e.g. by taking an xml fragment and converting
>   it.
>
> Wolfgang